What's the precision difference between ILS and GPS(LNAV/VNAV)?
What is the precision/accuracy difference between both GPS (LNAV/VNAV) and ILS?

Related: How precise is an ILS (Instrument landing system)?

Do you mean the specification of the approach or the operation of technology? Which of precision and accuracy do you want? Precision is repeatability with low variation and accuracy is how close you get to the real target. This is potentially four different answers.

I mean the operation of technology. Like how precise is one vs the other.

Corrected GPS technology is far more accurate and precise.
Focusing strictly on the technical operation of ILS vs GBAS GPS, a study directly compared the two long ago when GPS was being considered for use in precision approaches. GAST-D was an earlier name for what became GBAS (ground based augmentation system), which is the most accurate of the mainstream GPS approaches.
An A320 was equipped with a compliant ILS receiver and the new GPS equipment, linked to the ground station correction equipment. Six approaches were then flown against a reference localizer and approach. This chart shows the vertical GPS (red) deviations at less than 1m while ILS (blue) deviations were as much as 5m high and 8m low. Horizontal deviation for GPS was less than 0.5m while ILS was as much as 10m. The reference contains the technicalities of the methodology.


This is very interesting, but I'm not sure it answers the question. Of course GLS (and also LPV) will be at least similarly accurate as ILS, since both are augmented precision approaches. But the questions asked about non-precision LNAV/VNAV, which uses GPS without augmentation for lateral navigation and (in case of Baro-VNAV) barometric altimeter for vertical navigation. That's probably far less precise.

GPS + GBAS is an entirely different animal than GPS by itself.  LNAV/VNAV uses an IRS (or multiple) that receives GPS updates, but if we're just talking about LNAV/VNAV per se, you're into the realm of ANP values, which are typically a couple hundredths of a NM.  Good accuracy, but not at all the same as what's achievable with GBAS.

@Pilothead Thanks a lot for that info. As @ Ralph and @ Bianfable said, GPS+GBAS is a different animal though. I'm interested in knowing the difference between ILS and GPS by itself though.

OK, but I don't think anyone even makes uncorrected GPS equipment for aviation and you'd be nuts to turn it off just because you fly an approach that doesn't require it.  WAAS at least is used on LNAV/VNAV, so the difference with LPV is really only in the specification of the approach corridor which was excluded from the question. In any case I'll leave the answer.

"I don't think anyone even makes uncorrected GPS equipment for aviation" -> that may be true for newly designed aircraft, but most airliners that are flying today have neither SBAS nor GBAS receivers and therefore cannot fly LPV or GLS approaches. I think the A350 was the first one with both as standard. Also, many areas in the world are not yet covered by an SBAS; and GBAS is still very rare today.

@Bianfable OK, I'm curious and put that in a question.

@Bianfable that's a good point.

@Pilothead don't get me wrong, I appreciate your answer, I have no problem that you keep your answer, it is good data, is just not what I asked exactly, I wanted to compared ILS to GPS by itself only intentionally.

@Bianfable Many countries have ADS-B out mandates for commercial airliners which require SBAS in order to work properly, and retrofits have been created. The US put a mandate in place a decade ago but allowed many deferrals, the last of which expire this year. Many other countries/areas have as well including Europe, Australia, India, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Hong Kong and others on the way including China and Canada. The number of commercial aircraft now or in the near future in these places without SBAS is effectively zero. I think it's safe to say unaugmented GPS is obsolete.
